# d3.js tree - paging for many vertical child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm finding that the number of child nodes in a d3.js tree need to be constrained to prevent tight clustering of many nodes.

An extreme example:

[image]

I have been attempting to do this by grouping the child nodes where possible, but it gets to a point where this is no longer feasible.

It would be useful to have a layout where the number of child nodes to be displayed can be set, and a node (or whatever) at the end of the vertical list of nodes can be clicked to show the next lot of child nodes, which would also hide the upper batch of child nodes.

Another expanding node would then display at the top of that batch to show the previous batch of nodes and so on, with the number of child nodes displayed always constrained by the set value.

[image]

This is to show/hide nodes already in the JSON data.  How would this be achieved?

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amxf72q5/2/).

```
// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}


function update(source) {

const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
.domain( [ "Parent", "Child 1", "Child 2" ] )
.range( [ "#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb" ] );

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
           return colourScale(findParent(d))
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
         return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
           return 1;
        })
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        }
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
  .attr("opacity", "0.3")
   .style("stroke", function(d) {
                //return colourScale(findParentLinks(d));
            });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }
  
  function findParent(datum) {
  if (datum.depth < 2) {
    return datum.data.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.parent)
  }
}

function findParentLinks(datum) {
  if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
    return datum.target.name
  } else {
    return findParent(datum.target.parent)
  }
}

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(event, d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: The exanding nodes placeholders would be like scroll buttons, is that right? Clicking on them would show new nodes, at the same depth, while hiding others? That's how I am reading "with the number of child nodes displayed always constrained by the set value" and "a node (or whatever) at the end of the vertical list of nodes can be clicked to show the next lot of child nodes, which would also hide the upper batch of child nodes."

Comment: @AndrewReid In a way, yes like scroll buttons. However, unlike scroll buttons, the nodes (or whatever...)  at the end of the list of vertical nodes, would show the next batch of nodes in the JSON that aren't visible due to the limitation set in the script for the number to display.

Comment: The child nodes to be constrained are of two d.types (using d3.js 3.5.11 at this stage until I can finalise changes to work with v7) in my context.  The two d.types to be constrained, will be the most populous, hence the need to constrain.  They are in my application, d.type =='learning_event' and d.type == 'assessment'.  However for the purposes of this question, use whatever you want, but constrain, ideally d.types in the leaf nodes.

Comment: Also , yes the expanding buttons just work on the layer of child nodes in which they sit.

Comment: BTW the solution to this problem I expect would help a lot us d3.js users who have similar problems with large numbers of child nodes in a tree and limited space on a monitor to show them with having to scroll, pan or zoom.

Comment: Ok, I think we're on the same page. Will give it some thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var treeData = {
  "name": "Top Level",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Child 1",
      "children": [{
          "name": "C1"
        },
        {
          "name": "C2"
        },
        {
          "name": "C3"
        },
        {
          "name": "C4"
        },
        {
          "name": "C5"
        },
        {
          "name": "C6"
        },
        {
          "name": "C7"
        },
        {
          "name": "C8"
        },
        {
          "name": "C9"
        },
        {
          "name": "C10"
        },
        {
          "name": "C11"
        },
        {
          "name": "C12"
        },
        {
          "name": "C13"
        },
        {
          "name": "C14"
        },
        {
          "name": "C15"
        },
        {
          "name": "C16"
        },
        {
          "name": "C17"
        },
        {
          "name": "C18"
        },
        {
          "name": "C19"
        },
        {
          "name": "C20"
        },
        {
          "name": "C21"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Child 2",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of Child 2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of Child 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 90
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" +
    margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function pageNodes(d, maxNode) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, maxNode));
    if (d.children.length > maxNode) {
      d.pages = {}
      const count = maxNode - 2;
      const l = Math.ceil(d.children.length / count);
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        let startRange = i * count;
        let endRange = i * count + count;
        d.pages[i] = d.children.slice(startRange, endRange);
        d.pages[i].unshift({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: "..."
          },
          page: i == 0 ? l - 1 : i - 1
        })

        // console.log(i, d.pages[i]);
        d.pages[i].push({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: "..."
          },
          page: i != (l - 1) ? i + 1 : 0,
        });
      }
      d.children = d.pages[0];
    }
  }
}

root.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, 10));

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}


function update(source) {

  const colourScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["Parent", "Child 1", "Child 2"])
    .range(["#abacab", "#b67a4e", "#5a6fbb"]);

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180
  });

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d))
    });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
      return 1;
    })
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    })
    .attr("opacity", "0.3")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      //return colourScale(findParentLinks(d));
    });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return diagonal(d, d.parent)
    });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      }
      return diagonal(o, o)
    })
    .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  function findParent(datum) {
    if (datum.depth < 2) {
      return datum.data.name
    } else {
      return findParent(datum.parent)
    }
  }

  function findParentLinks(datum) {
    if (datum.target.depth < 2) {
      return datum.target.name
    } else {
      return findParent(datum.target.parent)
    }
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(event, d) {
    if (d.hasOwnProperty('page')) {
      d.parent.children = d.parent.pages[d.page];
    } else if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      d.children = d._children;
      d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/9g5z1pen/)

Comment: Looks pretty good.  Thanks.  The only problem I can see at this stage is when you get to the last batch, that level of child nodes disappears altogether.  Clicking the last expand node should show the first batch and so on.

Comment: I have forked your fiddle to better show the different named nodes of the children https://jsfiddle.net/o374ny18/1/

Comment: I'm having some issues with you solution using more complex data.  If I open a new question, would you look at it?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 yea sure, share new question link.

Comment: I got it to work at https://jsfiddle.net/9g5z1pen/   Is there anything in the pageNodes function that  in d3.js 3.5 (or something else) that would cause the first and last child nodes to have 'LE 1' as name and not '...'.?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 you can adjust the pageNodes function, I just adjusted it according to the shared image.

Comment: Thanks but I need some help and have managed to replicate the problem better with simpler data - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556779/d3-js-tree-paging-of-child-nodes-v3-5

Comment: @Chandan : Can you please help me with below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071064/paging-for-d3-tree-child-nodes