# d3.js Tree - Paging of child nodes v3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448591/d3-js-tree-paging-for-many-vertical-child-nodes/68495104?noredirect=1#comment121158532_68495104) which solves a problem with paging of many child nodes

There are few problems though with implementing in my d3.js context:

- The first and last child nodes that initiate the paging are not named
  '...' according to the script functionality.  This appears to be a v7 to v3.5 issue.
- The paging should only occur on the leaf nodes, not any middle
  branches.
- It needs to work with d3.js v3.5 (yes I know, but this is pending
  migrating the tree to v7...).  Basically the main issue is with naming of the first and last paging nodes...

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dy9vk6qe/) for implementation and issues in d3.js v3.5

Relevant from previous solution:

```
function pageNodes(d, maxNode) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, maxNode));
    if (d.children.length > maxNode) {
      d.pages = {}
      const count = maxNode - 2;
      const l = Math.ceil(d.children.length / count);
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        let startRange = i * count;
        let endRange = i * count + count;
        d.pages[i] = d.children.slice(startRange, endRange);
        d.pages[i].unshift({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: "..."
          },
          page: i == 0 ? l - 1 : i - 1
        })

        // console.log(i, d.pages[i]);
        d.pages[i].push({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: "..."
          },
          page: i != (l - 1) ? i + 1 : 0,
        });
      }
      d.children = d.pages[0];
      console.log(d.pages)
    }
  }
}
root.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, 8));

function click(d) {
if (d.hasOwnProperty('page')) {
      d.parent.children = d.parent.pages[d.page];
    }  else if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to enable paging on selected node group and want to name the paging nodes by some number

Comment: Not quite, I just need the paging nodes to show name as '...' as per your scipt.  That name shows OK in v7, but not v3.5.  I am converting my tree to v7, but there are number issues to resolve in the meantime.  So I would like your script to work in 3.5, which is basically does, just '...' is missing and replaced by a name of the first node in the child list.

Comment: Also. I just want the paging to work on leaf nodes, that is, nodes at the end of the tree.  You can just set the nodes to page only on the parent d.type (or d.data.type) == 'unit-group' which contain the leaf nodes I want paged.  I don't want other nodes in the tree to be paged, just the ones stemming from parent of d.type =="unit_group"

Comment: I have added answer with explanation if any issue please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Notes

- The order is mandatory `pageNodes` function needs to be called before collapse function call, As collapse changes the `children` key to `_children` and `pageNodes` function works with `children` key
- I created `pageNodes` function in a way so it does not require calling again and again which would waste computation power, so we call it once on start and the structure is adjusted as per requirement then we just work with click function without requiring to call `pageNodes` again and again.
- I have modified the `pageNodes` function to only page if data contain `page: true`, for reference you can check `unit-group` data segment.

### Example 1 - require adding page key in data to enable paging for selective data segment.

```js
var treeData = {"name":"Program","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program","children":[{"name":"ProgramGroup1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_group","children":[{"name":"POGroup1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"1program_outcome_group","children":[{"name":"PO1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome","children":[{"name":"Unit1","column_to_sort_by":"Unit1","children":[{"name":"UG1-LE","column_to_sort_by":null,"page":true,"type":"unit_group","children":[{"name":"LE1","column_to_sort_by":"LE1","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE10","column_to_sort_by":"LE10","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE11","column_to_sort_by":"LE11","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE12","column_to_sort_by":"LE12","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE13","column_to_sort_by":"LE13","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE14","column_to_sort_by":"LE14","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE15","column_to_sort_by":"LE15","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE2","column_to_sort_by":"LE2","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE4","column_to_sort_by":"LE4","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE5","column_to_sort_by":"LE5","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE6","column_to_sort_by":"LE6","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE7","column_to_sort_by":"LE7","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE8","column_to_sort_by":"LE8","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE9","column_to_sort_by":"LE9","type":"learning_event"}]},{"name":"UG1-Assessments","column_to_sort_by":null,"page":true,"type":"unit_group","children":[{"name":"ASST1","column_to_sort_by":"ASST1","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST10","column_to_sort_by":"ASST10","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST11","column_to_sort_by":"ASST11","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST13","column_to_sort_by":"ASST13","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST14","column_to_sort_by":"ASST14","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST15","column_to_sort_by":"ASST15","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST2","column_to_sort_by":"ASST2","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST3","column_to_sort_by":"ASST3","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST4","column_to_sort_by":"ASST4","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST5","column_to_sort_by":"ASST5","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST6","column_to_sort_by":"ASST6","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST7","column_to_sort_by":"ASST7","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST8","column_to_sort_by":"ASST8","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST9","column_to_sort_by":"ASST9","type":"assessment"}]}],"type":"unit"}]},{"name":"PO2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO3","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO4","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO5","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO6","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO7","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO8","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO9","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO10","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO11","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"}]},{"name":"POGroup2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"1program_outcome_group"}]},{"name":"ProgramGroup2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_group"}]};

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 2000 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function pageNodes(d, options) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, options));
    if (d.page && d.children.length > options.maxNode) {
      d.pages = {}
      const count = options.maxNode - 2;
      const l = Math.ceil(d.children.length / count);
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        const startRange = i * count;
        const endRange = i * count + count;
        let pageNumber = i == 0 ? l - 1 : i - 1;
        d.pages[i] = d.children.slice(startRange, endRange);
        d.pages[i].unshift({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: options.getLabel ? options.getLabel(pageNumber) : "..."
          },
          pageNumber,
          name: "..."
        })

        // console.log(i, d.pages[i]);
        pageNumber = i != (l - 1) ? i + 1 : 0;
        d.pages[i].push({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: options.getLabel ? options.getLabel(pageNumber) : "..."
          },
          pageNumber,
          name: "..."
        });
      }
      d.children = d.pages[0];
      console.log(d.pages)
    }
  }
}
root.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, {
  maxNode: 8,
}));

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

//svg.style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
      return d.color ? d.color : 'blue';
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "#ccc" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var collapseColor = d.color ? d.color : '#ccc';
      return d._children ? collapseColor : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty('pageNumber')) {
    d.parent.children = d.parent.pages[d.pageNumber];
  } else if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nLk4yptr/)

### Example 2 - through `page` options which is a function which would return true/false to enable/disable paging for selective data segment.

```
var treeData = {"name":"Program","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program","children":[{"name":"ProgramGroup1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_group","children":[{"name":"POGroup1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"1program_outcome_group","children":[{"name":"PO1","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome","children":[{"name":"Unit1","column_to_sort_by":"Unit1","children":[{"name":"UG1-LE","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"unit_group","children":[{"name":"LE1","column_to_sort_by":"LE1","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE10","column_to_sort_by":"LE10","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE11","column_to_sort_by":"LE11","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE12","column_to_sort_by":"LE12","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE13","column_to_sort_by":"LE13","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE14","column_to_sort_by":"LE14","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE15","column_to_sort_by":"LE15","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE2","column_to_sort_by":"LE2","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE4","column_to_sort_by":"LE4","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE5","column_to_sort_by":"LE5","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE6","column_to_sort_by":"LE6","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE7","column_to_sort_by":"LE7","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE8","column_to_sort_by":"LE8","type":"learning_event"},{"name":"LE9","column_to_sort_by":"LE9","type":"learning_event"}]},{"name":"UG1-Assessments","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"unit_group","children":[{"name":"ASST1","column_to_sort_by":"ASST1","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST10","column_to_sort_by":"ASST10","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST11","column_to_sort_by":"ASST11","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST13","column_to_sort_by":"ASST13","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST14","column_to_sort_by":"ASST14","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST15","column_to_sort_by":"ASST15","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST2","column_to_sort_by":"ASST2","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST3","column_to_sort_by":"ASST3","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST4","column_to_sort_by":"ASST4","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST5","column_to_sort_by":"ASST5","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST6","column_to_sort_by":"ASST6","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST7","column_to_sort_by":"ASST7","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST8","column_to_sort_by":"ASST8","type":"assessment"},{"name":"ASST9","column_to_sort_by":"ASST9","type":"assessment"}]}],"type":"unit"}]},{"name":"PO2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO3","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO4","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO5","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO6","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO7","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO8","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO9","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO10","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"},{"name":"PO11","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_outcome"}]},{"name":"POGroup2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"1program_outcome_group"}]},{"name":"ProgramGroup2","column_to_sort_by":null,"type":"program_group"}]};

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 2000 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function pageNodes(d, options) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, options));
    if (options.page && options.page(d) && d.children.length > options.maxNode) {
      d.pages = {}
      const count = options.maxNode - 2;
      const l = Math.ceil(d.children.length / count);
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        const startRange = i * count;
        const endRange = i * count + count;
        let pageNumber = i == 0 ? l - 1 : i - 1;
        d.pages[i] = d.children.slice(startRange, endRange);
        d.pages[i].unshift({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: options.getLabel ? options.getLabel(pageNumber) : "..."
          },
          pageNumber,
          name: "..."
        })

        // console.log(i, d.pages[i]);
        pageNumber = i != (l - 1) ? i + 1 : 0;
        d.pages[i].push({
          ...d.pages[i][0],
          data: {
            name: options.getLabel ? options.getLabel(pageNumber) : "..."
          },
          pageNumber,
          name: "..."
        });
      }
      d.children = d.pages[0];
      console.log(d.pages)
    }
  }
}
root.children.forEach(c => pageNodes(c, {
  maxNode: 8,
  page: function(d) {
    return d.type == "unit_group";
  }
}));

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);

//svg.style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
      return d.color ? d.color : 'blue';
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "#ccc" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var collapseColor = d.color ? d.color : '#ccc';
      return d._children ? collapseColor : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty('pageNumber')) {
    d.parent.children = d.parent.pages[d.pageNumber];
  } else if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/zek874wy/)

Comment: Brilliant!  I changed this line rather than adding page='true' to the JSON data.  Works fine:  if (d.type == 'unit_group' && d.children.length > options.maxNode) {...

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 I have added option to enable/disable paging in required data section without requiring data change.

Comment: Looks good! I will have a new question about this paging function.  This is to do with a Select2 list for searching the tree.  The paging is adding '...' to the select2 and not all the nodes of d.type == 'learning_event' as a result of the paging... .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570694/d3-js-tree-paging-with-search